# "sudo make x11-dist-install", no rule to generate

Tags: linux, opengl, glfw

So, I'm trying to getting setup on Ubuntu the [g-samples](https://github.com/g-truc/ogl-samples) of g-truc.

Installed `build-essentials` and a lot of dev mesa libs.

cmake works flawless.

However, the linux instructions are the following:

- Install the GLFW library included in the external directory. -- sudo make x11-dist-install
- Run CMake to create a makefile for GCC
- Launch the sample from the build output directory

But if I run `sudo make x11-dist-install` from within gl-samples/external/glfw-3.1.1

```
make: ***  no rule to generate "x11-dist-install" objective.  Stop.
```

According to [g-truc](https://github.com/g-truc/ogl-samples/issues/59), it looks like a glfw bug, but I don't know if it's really the case or I'm just doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I updated to glfw 3.2.1 and it worked

Downloaded `3.2.1.zip` [here](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/releases/tag/3.2.1), extracted along with 3.1.1, modified accordingly `CMakeLists.txt` as follow:

```
################################
# Add GLFW

set(GLFW_DIRECTORY glfw-3.2.1)
```

and reloaded